# build fail - Project with path ':transistorsoft-capacitor-background-fetch' could not be found in root project 'android'

Tags: flutter, build

When building, the following error occurs.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Project with path ':transistorsoft-capacitor-background-fetch' could not be found in root project 'android'.

My android/build.gradle file is below.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
          url("${project(':transistorsoft-capacitor-background-fetch').project.dir}/libs")
        }
    }
}


rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my android/app/build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    }
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.fluttersmsfirst"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.transistorsoft:tsbackgroundfetch:3.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

and my github is https://github.com/bisulight/flutter_first_sms.git

I wanted the build to be successful

Answer (score 0):

just go to background_fetch github, there is a help folder in which there is readme file for iOS and android, follow steps for configuring package for android app.

Link for readme file: https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch/blob/master/help/INSTALL-ANDROID.md.

I was also facing the same problem so I followed their android readme file then app build successfully. hopefully it will work for you too.